# curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL : ${...%?} doesn't work

Tags: bash, curl

I've been looking for a solution to my problem all the morning, especially in the 4 posts in https://stackoverflow.com having the same error name in their title but the solutions don't work for me.

I want to do several simple cURL requests put together in a Bash script. The request at the end of the file always works, whatever request it is. However the requests before return an error:

> curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

I am pretty sure that it has something to do with the carriage return in my file. But I don't know how to deal with it. As I show in the picture below I tried to use `${url1%?}`. I also tried `${url1%$'\r'}`, but it doesn't change anything.

Screenshot of file + results in terminal:

[image: screenshot of file + results in terminal]

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry... I hadn't see the existing question as I was looking for issues relating to curl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your lines end with `\r`, stripping away the `\r` from the `$url` won't work, because the line

```
curl -o NUL "{url1%?}
```

also ends with a `\r`, which is appended to the url argument again.

Comment out the `\r`, that is

```
url1="www.domain.tld/file"
curl -o NUL "${url1%?}" #
```

or

```
url1="www.domain.tld/file" #
curl -o NUL "$url1" #
```

or convert the file before executing it

```
tr -d '\r' < test.sh > testWithoutR.sh
```

Comment: The comment doesn't work (the terminal still detects it) but your last trick does, thanks. Do you know why the file put automatically a `\r` at the end of each line?

Comment: Adding null comments to the end of every line is a terrible suggestion, compared to simply saving the file with the expected newline characters in the first place.

Comment: Thank you chepner for putting in relation the other post with mine. I have changed the line endings format and now it works.