# Using a Bash variable in URL results in "curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL"

Tags: bash, curl

**Problem**

I'm trying to use a variable when calling a cURL command but it's including the the literal `$line` instead of the actual value.

```
while read line; do
  curl "https://x.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/$line?Type=carrier" -u "x:x" 
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

**Context**

I'm passing a list of numbers to the script trying to read them line by line.

Comment: What do you see when you replace  `curl` with `echo` ?

Comment: What output do you expect? $line to be translated to a shell variable value or something else?

Comment: if you go on https://www.twilio.com/lookup you see the command there I'm simply trying to make it read from a file a bunch of phone numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments we know that you're getting the following error:

> curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

If formatted this way:

```
while IFS="$IFS"$'\r' read line; do
  curl "https://x.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/$line?Type=carrier" -u "x:x" 
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

your command should work.

The problem is that your appending `\r` at the end of your input lines (so that every line of your input ends with a `\r\n` sequence). By default `read` does not strip trailing `r`. If we want `read` to trim those characters we have to add this character to the `IFS` environmental variable for `read` like this: `IFS="$IFS"$'\r')" read ...`.

---

Here's a great comment from [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy):

> Personally, I'd suggest `IFS=$' \t\n\r'`, not referring to the old `$IFS` value -- why make your code's behavior contextually dependent?

Another valuable comment; this time from [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner):

> Granted, a valid line probably isn't going to contain a `\r`, but conceptually, you don't want to treat a carriage return as whitespace; you just want to strip the `\r` that is part of the `\r\n` line ending. Instead of modifying `IFS`, read the line normally, then strip it with `line=${line%$'\r'}` before calling `curl`.

---

Related:

- [curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL : ${...%?} doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43609101/4694621)
- [Why is a shell script giving syntax errors when the same code works elsewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31886144/4694621)

Comment: Granted, a valid line probably isn't going to *contain* a `\r`, but conceptually, you don't want to treat a carriage return as whitespace; you just want to strip the `\r` that is part of the `\r\n` line ending. Instead of modifying `IFS`, read the line normally, then strip it with `line=${line%$'\r'}` before calling `curl`.

Comment: @chepner True. I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You try to address a variable and a text right after it, you should use `${VAR}` syntax:

```
curl "https://x.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/${line}?Type=carrier" -u "x:x" done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

The reason is bash tries to expand the parameter $line?Type .. instead of $line.

For example

```
[root@ ~]# line=1234
[root@ ~]# echo $line567

[root@ ~]# echo ${line}567
1234567
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting 
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Comment: This is not the case as `?` cannot be a  part of the variable name so it's perfectly OK to omit `{}` (at least in this case).

Comment: Can you add echo statement of the string before executing curl and show it here? `echo https://x.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/$line?Type=carrier`

Comment: `echo` isn't nearly as useful for showing nonprintable characters as `printf '%q\n' "https://x.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/$line?Type=carrier"` (which will properly quote and escape a trailing carriage return, f/e, which is what the accepted answer proposes)